# Firebase storing data from a snapshot?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, firebase

So I am trying to store the data from a snapshot following the API. This code prints the two strings that I want to save to the console. However I haven't been able to store them in the scope to display on the application page. I was wondering why I wasn't able to store this data and if there was any kind of way to work around this.

```
$scope.collectionList = [];
    //Loading up the publically available quote collections
    var publicCollectionsRef = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL + 'publicData/Collections/');
    publicCollectionsRef.once("value", function(snapshot) {
      // The callback function will get called twice, once for "fred" and once for "barney"
      snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
        var key = childSnapshot.key();
        console.log(String(key));
        $scope.collectionList.push(String(key));
      });
    });
```

I was trying to display a list of data... I wanted collectionList to be a list that I could use with ng-repeat. Basically all the children that were printed to the console in the snapshot I wanted in my variable. This was puzzling to me since the data was printing to the console just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the age old problem with Angular not knowing about external libraries. In order to get your current code to work, you'll have to wrap the code inside `.once()` in a `$timeout`.

```
$scope.collectionList = [];
//Loading up the publically available quote collections
var publicCollectionsRef = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL + 'publicData/Collections/');
publicCollectionsRef.once("value", function(snapshot) {
  // inject timeout into your controller
  $timeout(function() { 
    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
      var key = childSnapshot.key();
      console.log(String(key));
      $scope.collectionList.push(String(key));
     });
   });
});
```

**But, you shouldn't do that.**

**[Use AngularFire](http://angularfire.com).** Firebase (of which I am an employee of), created it's own integration of Angular (of which I am a maintainer of).

In your case you are trying to synchronize an array. That's exactly the type of thing AngularFire does.

```
angular.module('app', ['firebase']) // include AngularFire
  .constant('FirebaseUrl', '<my-firebase-app>')
  .service('rootRef', ['FirebaseUrl', Firebase])
  .factory('collectionList', CollectionList)
  .controller('MyCtrl', MyController);

function CollectionList(rootRef, $firebaseArray) {
  var collectionRef = rootRef.child('publicData/Collections/');
  return $firebaseArray(collectionRef);
} 

function MyController($scope, collectionList) {
  $scope.collectionList = collectionList;
}
```

AngularFire takes care of the array synchronization for you. In the `collectionList` factory, you create a `$firebaseArray` given the reference to the data's location.

The only difference in this code is that it does not use `.once()`, it uses `.on()` under the hood. So you'll be getting a realtime updating array, but AngularFire still handles all of that for you.